# Prediction returns NaN?

Tags: r, prediction, r-caret

I'm not sure what data to provide here and cannot provide a means to replicate the issue without sharing my full data. I can only provide the code and error message and hope that someone recognises this.

I have a model that uses ranger random forrest with a log transformed target variable "mod.rangerRF.logknn". My newdata has tens of thousands of records, however when I predict on it a small handful (5 to be exact) return NaN.

This only happens with the log version of the model.

Example with predicting on a single observation:

```
predict(mod.rangerRF.logknn, newdata = filter(p.test.knn, id == 31874))
[1] 15.40513
```

A number is returned which I can then back transform. This is the case for all but the 5 problem records which are returning NaN.

```
> predict(mod.rangerRF.logknn, newdata = filter(p.test.knn, id == 31873))
[1] NaN
```

A NaN which I cannot back transform.

Tens of thousands of rows, hundreds of features. Only 5 instances of NaN returned when running predict.

I'm not sure where to start in debugging this.

During preprocessing I ensured full data with no missing values. All data are numeric thanks to making use of dummy variables.

Does anyone recognise this problem? Any pointers on where I can look?

---

Per the comments here is the output of the model

```
> print(mod.rangerRF.logknn)
Random Forest 

30471 samples
  193 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 24376, 24376, 24378, 24377, 24377 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  RMSE       Rsquared 
   2    0.5125155  0.2832599
   5    0.4936741  0.3343648
  10    0.4845437  0.3592030
  20    0.4797720  0.3732469
  40    0.4778534  0.3790508

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the smallest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 40.
```

Comment: We need to see the data to help you. And possibly also the model

Comment: Can you post the output of `print(mod.rangerRF.logknn)` ?

Comment: Hi added above. If there's any other info I can provide please let me know

Comment: Also, since I used knnImpute for missing values, the data has been scaled. I wonder if this could be a factor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was just opened on Ranger's github: https://github.com/imbs-hl/ranger/issues/201

Hope that helps.